# Blocking styles from a single stylesheet on one div only

Tags: html, xhtml, css

I have a div located on a page. The issue is that it inherits global styles form a style sheet (Stylesheet A) such as global ul and table styles however, I would like this single div not to do so. I require the div in question to **only** obtain its styles from another stylesheet (stylesheet B). Currently they are clashing.

Is there any way to do this **without having to touch stylesheet A** in any way? This is because stylesheet A controls all the major styles of my site and the site is big enough that a change is likely to break something. The div in question holds unrelated data to the site and therefore does not require stylesheet A.

I am using javascript Prototype if that helps? No Jquery please :)

What about using an iframe? is this a valid solution and how would it work?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant CSS and HTML code and the order in which your stylesheets are being included in your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this would be to simply figure out every style attribute that div inherits from stylesheet A, then manually override those styles with stylesheet B.

If you wanted to put the div into an iframe, that should work as well.  You'd need that div to have its own HTML file, hosted on the same domain as the main page (otherwise you'll run into security issues).  Link to stylesheetB in the div page, and it would work.  You'd run into a few problems, though, in styling the iframe.  Since you can't read CSS properties in child documents from a parent document, you'd have to make the iframe a fixed width and height, which is limiting in many scenarios.  I guess you could let the iframe scroll, but that might not be want you want either.

I think the best way to do this is to use Chrome Inspect Element, or Firebug in Firefox to look at the CSS inheritances the div is receiving, then

Answer (score 1):

Any repeated styles will always apply the last one read.

Suppose you have this style: `.class { background-color: red; }` in your stylesheet A, and this one in B: `.class { background-color: blue; }` .

So, if you are calling your stylesheet A before B:

```
<link href="sheet_a.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="sheet_b.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then the style applied will be `.class { background-color: blue; }`, because it's the last one the browser read.

Now, if this is not working (if your stylesheets are being called in a different order, or the style in A is more specific than the one in B, so A is still being applied), you can use the [`!important` tag](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm).

`.class { background-color: blue !important; }` will overwrite the style in A, as long as it doesn't have !important also in the original one.

If it's only one element you want to change, you don't necessarily need a new stylesheet. You can have the new style between `<style></style>` tags in the html head, or inline in the element ( `<div style="background-color: blue;"></div>` ). Inline elements have more relevance than those on external sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inline styles](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) on the html structure or you can add `!important` on the rules that you want on **stylesheet b** to override styles on **stylesheet a**.

For example on **stylesheet b** you would do the following:

```
.element {background:red !important}
```